# Angle between sum of vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let $u,v$ and $w$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\theta(u,w), \theta(v,w)$ and $\theta(u+v,w)$ represent the angle between each listed pair of vectors. Does it hold that one of the following two statements must be true:
$$\theta(u,w) \geq \theta(u+v,w)$$ Or:
$$\theta(v,w) \geq \theta(u+v,w)$$
I feel this must be true and that it follows from some simple property that I'm forgetting. If it is true, does it generalize to any finite list of vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is true. Take the vectors $u=\langle-1, 1\rangle$, $v=\langle 1, 1\rangle$ and $w=\langle 0, -1\rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $u+v=\langle 0, 2\rangle$, and $\theta(u+v, w)=\pi$, while both $\theta(u,w)$ and $\theta(v,w)=\frac{3\pi}{4}$.